# Java cannot find symbol when calling a method from another class

Tags: java, class, methods

Im trying to call the method show in the klub class, from my demo class, and to call the method visAlleAtleter in the demo class (from my klub class), but I get an error saying it can't find the symbol and then the name of the method. I have tried to specify where I want it from, but I'm not certain how to do it. This is my Klub class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Klub {
    
    private String navn;
    private ArrayList<Atlet> atleter;

    public Klub(String navn) {
       this.navn = navn;
       atleter = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public void addAtlet(Atlet atlet) {
        atleter.add(atlet);
    }
    
    public void visAlleAtleter() {
        System.out.println(navn);
        for(Atlet atlet: atleter) {
            atlet.display();
            
        }
        
    }
    public void visAlleAtleter2(boolean samletValue) {
      if(samletValue = true) {
          Atlet.show();
        } else {
            
        }
    }
}
```

this is my Demo class

```
public class Demo { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Klub minKlub = new Klub("SWU United");
       

        Atlet atlet1 = new Atlet("Pan", "Tennis", 43.5, 21);
        Atlet atlet2 = new Atlet("Peter", "Golf", 41.5, 29);
        Atlet atlet3 = new Atlet("Robby", "Tennis", 43.5, 20);
        Atlet atlet4 = new Atlet("Niklas Klein", "Maisball", 21.2, 23);
        Atlet atlet5 = new Atlet("Linni Maister", "Maisball", 44.1, 32);
        Atlet atlet6 = new Atlet("Dennis Michael", "Maisball", 32.5, 11);
        minKlub.addAtlet(atlet1);
        minKlub.addAtlet(atlet2);
        minKlub.addAtlet(atlet3);
        minKlub.addAtlet(atlet4);
        minKlub.addAtlet(atlet5);
        minKlub.addAtlet(atlet6);
   
         Klub.visAlleAtleter();

    
    
    } 
    
}
```

and my atlet class

```
public class Atlet {

    private String navn;
    private String sportsgren;
    private double pris;
    private int alder;

    public Atlet(String navn, String sportsgren, double pris, int alder) {
    
    this.navn = navn;
    this.sportsgren = sportsgren;
    this.pris = pris;
    this.alder = alder;
    
    }
    
    public void oppdaterPris(double nyPris) {
        pris = nyPris;
    }
    
    public double getPris() {
        return pris;
    }
    
    public double predSalgspris() {
        return pris-0.95*Math.abs(25-alder);
    }
    
    public void display() {
        System.out.println(navn + " (" + alder + ") - " + 
        sportsgren + ": " + pris + "kr (" + predSalgspris() + "kr)");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: visAlleAtleter() is not a static class. You should use minKlub.visAlleAthleter(),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `visAlleAtleter` is not static so your can't call it as you do `Klub.visAlleAtleter()`.
Just call method on object `minKlub.visAlleAtleter()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the line `Klub.visAlleAtleter();` in the `main` method in `Demo`. To correct this you have to replace it with `minKlub.visAlleAtleter();`.

The reason for this is that according to your code, you have an instance of the class `Klub` called `minKlub`. The method `visAlleAtleter()` is bound to any instance of the class `Klub`, not the class `Klub` itself.

EDIT:
To illustrate why your attempt could be an issue, consider this example:

```java
public class Demo { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Klub minKlub = new Klub("SWU United");
        Klub dinKlub = new Klub("SEU United")
       
        Atlet atlet1 = new Atlet("Pan", "Tennis", 43.5, 21);
        Atlet atlet2 = new Atlet("Peter", "Golf", 41.5, 29);
        minKlub.addAtlet(atlet1);
        minKlub.addAtlet(atlet2);

        Atlet atlet3 = new Atlet("Mads", "Fotball", 123, 123);
        Atlet atlet4 = new Atlet("Mikkelsen", "Curling", 123, 123);
        dinKlub.addAtlet(atlet3);
        dinKlub.addAtlet(atlet4);
   
        Klub.visAlleAtleter();
    }    
}
```

In this example, when calling `Klub.visAlleAtleter()`, it is impossible to know whether Java should call the method on `minKlubb` or `dinKlubb`. Its important that you see `minKlub` and `dinKlub` as physical instances of the `Klub` class.

Coincidentally, writing `Klub.someArbitraryMethod()` is actually a commonly used feature in java, where `someArbitraryMethod()` is statically declared. This way of writing is only possible if you declare the method as `static`:

```java
public static void someArbitraryMethod() {...}
```

This means that the method doesn't belong to any physical instances of the class `Klub`, but rather it belongs to the class `Klub` itself. Doing

```
minKlubb.someArbitraryMethod();
```

will therefor cause a compilation error.